# spark dataframe update values in nested json

Tags: arrays, json, apache-spark, bigdata, jsonparser

I am trying to do transformation on a json dataset which has multiple levels of nested elements data .So based on a configuration it should apply the tranformation logic. I am ble to do the tranformation but its adding a new column instead of updating the inner nested elements.Below is the code snippet and input

**orders.json**

```
    {
        "order": {
            "id": "2023-04-01",
            "name": "John Doe",
            "address": {
                "street": "123 Main St",
                "city": "New York",
                "state": "NY",
                "zipcode": "10001"
            },
            "orders": [
                {
                    "order_id": 1001,
                    "quarter": "2023-06-30",
                    "items": [
                        {
                            "item_id": 1,
                            "name": "Product 1",
                            "price": 10.99
                        },
                        {
                            "item_id": 2,
                            "name": "Product 2",
                            "price": 20.99
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "order_id": 1002,
                    "quarter": "2023-06-29",
                    "items": [
                        {
                            "item_id": 3,
                            "name": "Product 3",
                            "price": 15.99
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    }
```

**orders_modify.json configuration**

```
    [
        {
            "name": "order.orders.quarter",
            "udf": "getQuarterOfYearUDF"
        }
    ]
```

****Java code to update inner nested json based on config entry ****

```java
    import com.google.gson.Gson;
    import com.google.gson.reflect.TypeToken;
    import org.apache.spark.sql.*;
    import org.apache.spark.sql.api.java.UDF1;
    import org.apache.spark.sql.types.DataTypes;
    import org.nypd.nextgen.spark.sql.udfs.ScalaUDFs;
    
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.lang.reflect.Type;
    import java.nio.file.Files;
    import java.nio.file.Paths;
    import java.util.List;
    
    
    public class UDFFullReplace {
    
    
        public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    
            // Create SparkSession
            SparkSession spark = SparkSession.builder()
                .appName("UDFRegistrationExample")
                .master("local")
                .getOrCreate();
    
            spark.udf().register("getQuarterOfYearUDF", getQuarterOfYearUDF, DataTypes.IntegerType);
            //spark.udf().register("getQuarterOfYearUDF", getQuarterOfYearUDF, DataTypes.IntegerType);
    
            // Load JSON data into DataFrame
            String jsonPath = "/home/akannan/INPUT/orders.json"; // Specify the path to your JSON file
            Dataset<Row> jsonDF = spark.read().option("inferSchema", "true").option("multiLine", "true").json(jsonPath);
            jsonDF.printSchema();
            jsonDF.show(false);
    
            // Read the config file
            String configPath = "/home/akannan/INPUT/orders_modify.json"; // Specify the path to your config file
            String configFileContents = new String(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(configPath)));
            Gson gson = new Gson();
            Type listType = new TypeToken<List<FieldTransformation>>() {
            }.getType();
            List<FieldTransformation> transformations = gson.fromJson(configFileContents, listType);
    
            // Apply field transformations dynamically
            Dataset<Row> updatedDataFrame = applyTransformations(jsonDF, transformations);
    
            // Show the updated DataFrame
            updatedDataFrame.show(false);
    
            // Close SparkSession
            spark.close();
        }
    
    
    
    
        static Dataset<Row> applyTransformations(Dataset<Row> jsonDF, List<FieldTransformation> transformations) {
            Dataset<Row> transformedDF = jsonDF;
            for (FieldTransformation transformation : transformations) {
                String[] fieldNames  = transformation.getName().split("\\.");
                String columnName = fieldNames[fieldNames.length - 1 ];
                String nestedColumnAccessor = String.join(".",fieldNames);
    
                transformedDF = jsonDF.selectExpr("*",
                    "transform(order.orders, x -> struct(x.order_id, getQuarterOfYearUDF(x.quarter), x.items)) as orders"
                );
    
            }
            return transformedDF;
        }
    
        static class FieldTransformation {
            private String name;
            private String udf;
    
            public String getName() {
                return name;
            }
    
            public void setName(String name) {
                this.name = name;
            }
    
            public String getUdf() {
                return udf;
            }
    
            public void setUdf(String udf) {
                this.udf = udf;
            }
        }
    
        static UDF1<String, Integer> getQuarterOfYearUDF = (dateString) -> {
            String[] parts = dateString.split("-");
            int month = Integer.parseInt(parts[1]);
            int quarter = (month - 1) / 3 + 1;
            return quarter;
        };
    
    }
```

This is giving a new column orders but what i am not able  to replace the value in the original json for order.orders.quarter field .Any pointers or help appreciated.

**OUTPUT**

```
    +-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
    |order                                                                                                                                                                        |orders                                                                |
    +-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
    |{{New York, NY, 123 Main St, 10001}, 2023-04-01, John Doe, [{[{1, Product 1, 10.99}, {2, Product 2, 20.99}], 1001, 2023-06-30}, {[{3, Product 3, 15.99}], 1002, 2023-06-29}]}|[{1001, 2, [{1, Product 1,
10.99}, {2, Product 2, 20.99}]}, {1002, 2, [{3, Product 3, 15.99}]}]|
    +-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```